# Is there a way to change the x ticks to strings (say time) on pyqtgraph and keep the autoformat so the tick dont bunch up

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

The end goal would be to run this for a while with a 1 second pause and show the last hour (if it can handle that),so n = 3600 and t something higher . It plots well with  line 37 (ax.setTicks(dx)) commented out, but I would like to display the time on the x-axis. If I uncomment that line, the xticks have the time, but they dont autoformat and bunch up on each other.  Is setTickSpacing the right way to fix this? I've tried it and I couldn't get it to work in this case.

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import time
import datetime as dt

x = []
y = []

timelist = []

pw = pg.plot(x, y)

n = 25
i = 0
t = 500

while i < t:
    if i < n:
        xdata = i
        x.append(xdata)

    currentTime = (dt.datetime.now()).strftime("%M:%S")
    timelist.append(currentTime)
    timelist = timelist[-n:]

    ticks = [list(zip(range(n), timelist))]
    ydata = np.random.randint(0,9)
    y.append(ydata)
    y = y[-n:]

    pw.plot(x, y, pen = 'y', clear=True)

    ax = pw.getAxis('bottom')
    dx = [value for value in ticks]
    #ax.setTicks(dx)

    #ax.setTickSpacing(0,0,0)

    pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    time.sleep(.01)
    i = i + 1

if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to correctly build the information of the ticks, also you should not use an infinite loop or `sleep()`, instead use `QTimer`.

```py
import datetime as dt
import sys

import numpy as np

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


x, y, timelist = [], [], []

n, i, t = 25, 0, 500

pw = pg.plot(x, y)


def on_timeout():
    global i, x, y, timelist
    if i < n:
        x.append(i)
    i += 1
    ydata = np.random.randint(0, 9)
    y.append(ydata)
    y = y[-n:]

    pw.plot(x, y, pen="y", clear=True)

    currentTime = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S")
    timelist.append(currentTime)
    timelist = timelist[-n:]

    ticks = list(enumerate(timelist))
    ax = pw.getAxis("bottom")
    ax.setTicks([ticks])


timer = QtCore.QTimer(timeout=on_timeout, interval=100)
timer.start()
pw.win.showMaximized()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, "PYQT_VERSION"):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: This works for n = 25, but not if you increase n.  There's still the issue of the ticks bunching up

Comment: @alex25 Obviously if there is such a large number of ticks they will overlap, how do you want the ticks distributed for n = 3600 so that they do not overlap?

Comment: If you run my original code with a high n and the set ticks commented out, the x ticks auto format as it builds up...starts with 1,2,3... then 10, 20, 30... then 100,200,300...etc.  I was hoping to do something like that where the tick would just say the time from that point instead of a number.  Also I'm trying to do this without functions if possible.  I'm putting this in something else and haven't had luck with functions running properly in it

Comment: @alex25 1) okay, I understand that the resolution decreases if the number is large, 2) I will use the most readable method and that implies using functions, classes, etc. I don't understand why you don't want to use functions, what advantages do you think it has do not use functions?

Comment: I've just had nothing but issues trying to use them with the rest of the code. I 'd rather just keep the code as simple as possible.  If I need to add one in to fix the tick marks auto formatting, then so be it, but I'd rather not rewrite the rest of the code that's already working properly with the rest of what im going to be putting into.  I was hoping that there was a simple solution, such as settickspacing, but I tried that and it didnt change anything

Comment: @alex25 There is nothing magical, on the other hand not to use functions does not imply a simple code, on the contrary since it makes a dirty code. Tomorrow maybe I will post some update.

Comment: This has drifted so far away from my original question.  I was hoping there was a way to use setTickSpacing to fix the bunching up issue.  I was assuming that the "levels" listed in the documentation referred to the autoformatting as the x axis got larger, but I'm probably wrong about that.  I'd tried ax.setTickSpacing([(0,1),(0, 10),(0, 100)]) thinking this would make the spacing larger as the x axis expanded, but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time but it's relatively straightforward in the end. You cannot use setTicks with autoformattingb but you can create a list or a dict of axis values in your plotting class and access it in AxisItem class. It's not exactly a pretty solution but it does work.

Subclass AxisItem for X axis:

```
class customAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [Plotter.timeValues[int(v)-1] for v in values]
```

Then tell the plotter to use the axis and create the list of tickvalues:

```
class Plotter():
    (...)
    self.chartWidget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': CustomAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
    self.timeValues = [0.25, 0.50, 0.759]
    (...)
```